# Flutter app run issue - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':platform_device_id' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

In .yaml file platform_device_id: ^1.0.1
',I need to fix app run issues.

Comment: update your Kotlin version and gradle version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error due to the latest version of Gradle used in the project.`platform_device_id` Package contains a lower Gradle and Kotlin version that is not supported to build with the latest Gradle version.

There's also a GitHub issue ongoing, you can check it out with this [link](https://github.com/BestBurning/platform_device_id/issues/32)

The solution is to use this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) called `device_info_plus` instead. It is presented by the Flutter community itself so it works seamlessly as you expected. Also, it works will all platforms.